# Animating block height from 0 to auto

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to create animation using .animate. I want block to have height: 0px, so I used CSS.

Normally,

Block doesn't have height (I believe it's auto, if value is not set?), but block has content in it. So height comes from what is inside it.

I want my block to animate height 0 to auto. So I did this:

```
.panelContainer {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and

```
(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panelContainer").animate({
        height: "auto"
    }, 1000);
});
```

But somehow my block height doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `.slideDown()` function. 
I've already created a fiddle file: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RWeEs/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.panelContainer').slideDown(1000);
});
```

When the site comes up the `panelContainer` slides down.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is `.slideToggle()`: it does *exactly* the kind of animation you are looking for.

```
$('.panelContainer').slideToggle();
```

From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/):

> The `.slideToggle()` method animates the height of the matched elements.
>   This causes lower parts of the page to slide up or down, appearing to
>   reveal or conceal the items.

Comment: This is what I mean, but slideToggle does "animation" differently. SlideToggle moves and adds height at the same time. Which is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `height: toggle` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panelContainer").animate({
        height: "toggle"
    }, 1000);
});
```